# How to find continuous days between two dates

Tags: sql, group-by, amazon-redshift, gaps-and-islands

I have scenario like in the picture, where the date of an item availability is not continues. I want to find out, every time when it becomes available, how long does it stay continuously in the website.

I want to find out like below for each item in my table:
[image]

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical gaps and island problem.

Here is one approach using window functions:

```
select 
    item, 
    min(available_date) min_available_date, 
    max(available_date) max_available_date, 
    count(*) no_days
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        sum(case when available_date = lag_available_date + interval '1' day then 0 else 1 end) 
            over(
                partition by item 
                order by available_date
                rows between unbounded preceding and current row
            ) grp
    from (
        select 
            t.*, 
            lag(available_date) 
                over(partition by item order by available_date) lag_available_date
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
group by item, grp
order by item, min_available_date
```

The most inner query recovers the date of the "previous" record. The next level does a window sum that increase by `1` everytime dates are not consecutive: this defines the groups. Then, the outer query aggregates by group.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3025ab1259d81f0cea182d84fe61f4d7)**

Sample data:

```
item | available_date
:--- | :-------------
ABA  | 2019-01-04    
ABA  | 2019-01-05    
ABA  | 2019-01-06    
ABA  | 2019-01-07    
ABA  | 2019-01-12    
ABA  | 2019-01-15    
ABA  | 2019-01-16    
ABA  | 2019-01-17    
ABA  | 2019-01-19    
ABA  | 2019-01-21    
ABA  | 2019-01-22
```

Query results:

```
item | min_available_date | max_available_date | no_days
:--- | :----------------- | :----------------- | ------:
ABA  | 2019-01-04         | 2019-01-07         |       4
ABA  | 2019-01-12         | 2019-01-12         |       1
ABA  | 2019-01-15         | 2019-01-17         |       3
ABA  | 2019-01-19         | 2019-01-19         |       1
ABA  | 2019-01-21         | 2019-01-22         |       2
```

Comment: Gaps and islands are such a common problem, and yet so clunky to express, that it makes you wonder when they'll introduce a specific operator in SQL to number groups of contiguous values.